# Tensorboard Graph with custom training loop does not include my Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I have created my own loop as shown in the TF 2 migration guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#write_your_own_loop).
I am currently able to see the graph for only the `--- VISIBLE ---` section of the code below. How do I make my model (defined in the `---NOT VISIBLE---` section) visible in tensorboard?

If I was not using a custom training loop, I could have gone with the [documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs#train_the_model_and_log_data) `model.fit approach`:

```
model.fit(..., callbacks=[keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)])
```

In TF 1, the approach used to be quite straightforward:

```
tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR, sess.graph)
```

The Tensorboard migration guide clearly states ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/migrate#additional_tips)) that:

> No direct writing of tf.compat.v1.Graph - instead use @tf.function and trace functions

```
configure_default_gpus()
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True)
K = tf.keras
dataset = sanity_dataset(BATCH_SIZE)

#-------------------------- NOT VISIBLE -----------------------------------------
model = K.models.Sequential([
    K.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_CHANNELS)),
    K.layers.Dense(10, activation=K.layers.LeakyReLU()),
    K.layers.Dense(IMG_WIDTH * IMG_HEIGHT * IMG_CHANNELS, activation=K.layers.LeakyReLU()),
    K.layers.Reshape((IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_CHANNELS)),
])
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss_fn = K.losses.Huber()


@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(inputs, training=True)
#-------------------------- VISIBLE ---------------------------------------------
        pred_loss = loss_fn(targets, predictions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(pred_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return pred_loss, predictions


with tf.summary.create_file_writer(LOG_DIR).as_default() as writer:
    for epoch in range(5):
        for step, (input_batch, target_batch) in enumerate(dataset):
            total_loss, predictions = train_step(input_batch, target_batch)

            if step == 0:
                tf.summary.trace_export(name="all", step=step, profiler_outdir=LOG_DIR)
            tf.summary.scalar('loss', total_loss, step=step)
            writer.flush()
writer.close()
```

There's a [similar unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639731/tensorboard-for-custom-training-loop-in-tensorflow-2) where the OP was unable to view any graph.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a better way, but I just realized that a simple workaround is to just use the existing tensorboard callback logic:

```
tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(LOG_DIR)
tb_callback.set_model(model) # Writes the graph to tensorboard summaries using an internal file writer
```

If you want, you could write your own summaries into the same directory it uses: `tf.summary.create_file_writer(LOG_DIR + '/train')`.

[image: Tensorboard Graph and Scalars]

Comment: Where do you place this code in the custom training loop? When I run it, I get no scalars